# Django: Email-Verification at User Registration

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-allauth

So I'm trying to implement an Email-Verification for my Project, so every time a User registers on my Webpage, he has to verify his Email-Address in order to create his account.
I understand, that Django-Allauth (https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) offers this kind of behavior, but neither the docs nor the tutorials helped me understand how to actually go about it.
I know this question is a little vague and to much to ask for, but can anybody give me a hint how I actually start implementing the Verification?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation and source:

- set `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED` to `True` and `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION` to `'mandatory'` ([ref](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html))
- [An email will be sent to the user as they try to log in](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/845aa5730636c07b305af0d28e6ea8c530f81657/allauth/account/utils.py#L147-L157)
- The email will contain a link pointing to [the confirmation view](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/c4d7b41008325cc4689e54c4f886596e755d643a/allauth/account/views.py#L265).

Comment: How can I redirect to verification sent after I send confirmation email? I have implemented sending an email, but I would like to redirect to custom `verification_sent.html` so that users can update incorrect email addresses as well. I would appreciate any help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64363966/redirect-to-email-confirm-html-after-signup-using-django-allauth