# Redirect after signup using django-allauth to custom verification page

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-allauth

I have a custom signup page and I would like to send email verification after user creation. However, I would like to redirect users to a different template after signup which shows them a message that they need to verify their email address.

Currently my view is:

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)  
            #user.is_active = True
            user.save()
            send_email_confirmation(request, user, True)
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'main/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

How can I redirect users to a the template `verification_sent.html`? I have also implemented a method for users to change the email address if incorrect but I cannot find how I can integrate that in my `verification_sent.html` template.

Comment: Upon submission of their username / password you can redirect them on the front end. 1) send a request to the backend with the username password, 2) create a new user in the backend, send an email in the backend, send a response to the front end, 3) upon receiving a successful response in the front end, redirect the user

Answer (score 1):

In this example we use ajax to send the user registration data to the backend. If the backend successfully registers a new user we return a response object. Upon retrieving the response object, js will redirect the user to the verification page.

script.js:

```
function register() {

  // conduct ajax request:
  $.ajax({
    url : 'register',
    data : {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken : 'the_token',
      username : 'the_username',
      password : 'the_password',
    },
    success : register_success, // reference to function below:
  })

} $('#register').click(register); // execute function when register button is clicked

// executes upon retrieving a successful response from backend:
function register_success(response) {

  // unpack response:
  status = response.status;
  
  // redirect users with okay status:
  if (status=='okay') window.location('verification');

}
```

views.py:

```
def register(request):

   # unpack request:
   username = request.POST['username']
   password = request.POST['password']

   # register user, send email:
   ...

   # pack response:
   response = json.dumps({
       'status' : 'okay' # or other status for failed registration attempts
   })

   return HttpResponse(response)
```